# Custom mail driver in Laravel 8

Tags: email, queue, laravel-8

I'm using a custom mail driver with Laravel 8. It's good to work with direct mailing. But after using it should queue, an issue was found.

> "Target class [mail.manager] does not exist."

I have already registered at config/app.php for customMailServiceProvider. The problem is only for when using shouldqueue at Notifications with mail. Any ideas or any suggestions? I was following the instruction for the following article.

https://www.delenamalan.co.za/2020/laravel-custom-mail-driver.html#create-a-custom-mail-transport-class

Answer (score 0):

Add This code line at app/bootstrap.php

```
$app->alias('mail.manager', Illuminate\Mail\MailManager::class);
```

This is worked for me. Laravel Queue don't know the facades name "mail.manager".

Don't forget to run `compose dump` after code update.

Answer (score 0):

In **Providers/CustomMailServiceProvider.php** change from:

```php
class CustomMailServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
```

to

```php
class CustomMailServiceProvider extends MailServiceProvider
{
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).